# A valid use for traits

Tags: php, oop

In my application I have a `Config` object which my service layer and views have as a class property. Any time I want a config value I have to do

```
$configValue = $this->config->setting('setting.name');
```

What I want to be able to do each time I want a setting is

```
$configValue = $this->config('setting.name');
```

To accomplish this I have now put this code within my `AbstractService` and `AbstractView` I have

```
protected function config($setting) {
    return $this->config->setting($setting);
}
```

It is only a tiny little bit of code duplication but I would still prefer to not have it so would it be the right choice to use traits here?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for the magic [`__invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) function (requires 5.3+, but since you use traits I assume you have this):

```
<?php
    class Config {
        private $config = array(
            'ip'   => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 12345
        );

        public function setting($option) {
            if (!empty($this->config[$option])) {
                return $this->config[$option];
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function __invoke($option) {
            return $this->setting($option);
        }
    }

    $config = new Config();
    var_dump($config('ip')); //127.0.0.1
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/sQgC3)

Comment: I just tried it in one of my views and when I do `$this->config('setting.name')` I get an error because PHP is looking for a method in my view called `config`. I have not tried this yet but doing `$config = $this->config; $config('setting.name');` would probably work because it will not look for the method `config` in my view but then this defeats the whole purpose of me having to write less code to get a config value.